# media query not working properly in vs code

Tags: html, css, frontend, responsiveness

```
`@media(min-width:300px)and(max-width:400px){
    div{
        background-color: pink;
    }
}`
```

I tried this while learning responsive websites. But in vs code this is not working. I had also checked for any updates in vs code but there's no update at this moment.

```
`@media(min-width:300px)and(max-width:400px){
    div{
        background-color: pink;
    }
}`
```

I want this to be done

Comment: What is not working? Is highlighting not working or what? Also, both codes you gave are same or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the space before and after "and", this should work:

```css
@media (min-width:300px) and (max-width:400px){
    div{
        background-color: pink;
    }
}
```